# How to build Boost 1.44 using VS 2015

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, build

I am working on legacy projects upgrade from VS2010 to VS2015. for that **boost1.44** should be recompiled using **VS2015** and i tried to rebuild it. I got following errors:

1) `libs\regex\build\has_icu_test.cpp(12) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/uversion.h': No such file or directory`

2)`error C2280: 'boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals::detail::basic_connection>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals::detail::basic_connection> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

3) `error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'boost::fusion::tuple'`

4) `warning`:`Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results`

How to resolve these issues without upgrading boost? or is it mandatory to upgrade boost to higher version to compile using VS2015?

Comment: Note the list of compilers this release [was tested with](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_44_0.html). Do you have enough time and experience to test it, and fix any problems you encounter? | IMHO it would be more valuable to patch your code to work with an up-to-date version of boost that has been tested and supports your toolset.

Answer (score 0):

boost 1.44 was released long before VS 2015 so this compiler is not supported. Besides many bugs were fixed in boost since that time. You should update boost to the latest version.

Also the error #1 seems to be caused by missing [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: is that means can't build boost1.44 using VS2015 in anyway?

Comment: Well, nothing is impossible, but that would be just a waste of time.